# lua not found in $PATH On Cloud9 Terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, lua, installation, cloud9

So Recently i was Trying to Use LUA Programming language for Some Projects,
So i wanted to use Cloud9 to Use My LUA Codes, and try them.

In the Terminal, any version of LUA is not Installed,
I wanted to use luarocks (2.2.2), i Downloaded & Unpacked luarocks,
in luarocks Directory, I Typed the Following:

```
./configure
```

After That, it gave this Result:

```
Looking for Lua... lua not found in $PATH. You may want to use the flags --with-lua, --with-lua-bin and/or --lua-suffix. See --help.
```

So What's the Problem i have?,
is it because Cloud9 Doesn't Support LUA or Something?, OR Should i install it by my self?,

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is that you don't have lua installed. Cloud9 support lua. By default like many distro, it doesn't install lua. You have to install it separately like this:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install lua5.2 liblua5.2
```

You need to do update. Otherwise, you won't be able to install liblua5.2 . Then you can install luarocks as mentioned in the luarock's site:

```
git clone git://github.com/keplerproject/luarocks.git
cd luarocks
./configure
make build
sudo make install
```

Comment: I guess you mean $ `sudo apt-get install lua5.2 liblua5.2 liblua5.2-dev`

Comment: @KnudLarsen While that's correct. I get Note, selecting 'liblua5.2-dev' for regex 'liblua5.2' . So liblua5.2-dev is also require for functioning of liblua5.2 so it get pulled when you do sudo apt-get install liblua5.2.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Even though, generally you need to install dev for headers separately, this is one of the few packages where dev is require for appropriate behvaiour of lib.